# Trouble proving approximation for quantum simulation using Zassenhaus formula

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-computation, quantum-information

I would like to prove the following
$e^{i(A+B)\Delta t} = e^{\frac{iA\Delta t}{2}}e^{iB\Delta t}e^{\frac{iA\Delta t}{2}} + \mathcal{O}(\Delta t ^3)$. I have tried to prove it using Zassenhaus formula but i didn't succeed. Can anyone please help with this proof? Thank you

Comment: try expanding the Taylor series

Comment: Thank you for answering. I actually followed the steps showed here [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3253338/power-of-approximate-exponential-of-operator-sum) to start the calculation but it seems i can't get my head around the last line of the explanation when we want to eliminate the $\mathcal{O}(t^2)$ terms. That is actually what's blocking me... How do we proceed to eliminate the terms of order  $\mathcal{O}(t^2)$?

Comment: What do you get for the $t^2$ term?

Comment: Doing the Taylor expansion of $e^{i(A+B)\Delta t}$, the second term gives $\frac{-(A+B)^2 \Delta t^2}{2!}$. I don't think i see how i can eliminate the $\mathcal{O}(t^2)$ using the Taylor Series... Am I missing something out ? Thank you

Comment: Compare it to the other expression's $t^2$ term.

Comment: So, is the answer acceptable?

Comment: Are you referring to the answer proposed by  user619894 ?

Answer (score 1):

Simplify notation by $\Delta t \equiv t$.

The Zassenhaus formula is wild overkill. Just use the well-known leading CBH expansion, after multiplying both sides of your target expression by $e^{ {-iA t/2}} $,
$$e^{ {-iA t/2}} e^{it(A+B) } - e^{itB }e^{ iA  t/2} \\
=e^{ it(B+A /2) +t^2[A,B]/4 + \mathcal{O}( t ^3)} - e^{ it(B+A /2) +t^2[A,B]/4 + \mathcal{O}( t ^3)}   =  \mathcal{O}( t ^3).$$
The right hand side will be unaffected by multiplication by $e^{ iA t/2}$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I have a question about the answer. I am wondering where is the first line coming from exactly? I can't seem to figure it out. Thanks again (Edit: Sorry if this is a trivial question)

Comment: I moved the right hand side of your target expression to the left, and multiplied both sides by the evident exponential.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer.

Comment: I stuck the statement into my answer.